# remove everything after the last occurrence of numerical value

Tags: c#

I need to remove everything after the last occurrence of a numerical value some examples below:

`1234D` Should be `1234`
`ABCD1234A_BC` Should be `ABCD1234`

Comment: Your algorithm is not clear. I don't see the relation between `ABCD1234A_BC` and `ABCE1234`. What happens to the `D` and where does the `E` come from?

Comment: It's probably just a typo. Don't be such a nitpick ;)

Comment: Can you also post result of you expectation so it will be more clear of what has to be done?

Comment: I've edited out what was assumed to be a typo.  If that wasn't what you meant, please update the question.

Answer (score 2):

This method should do it for you:

```
public string StripAfterLastNumber(string s)
{
       int index= s.LastIndexOfAny("0123456789".ToCharArray());
       return s.Remove(index+1);
}
```

**Shortened Version:**

```
public string StripAfterLastNumber(string s)
{
    return s.Remove(s.LastIndexOfAny("0123456789".ToCharArray())+1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A rather roundabout way of doing this:

```
string testString = "1234D";
string result = testString.Substring(0, testString.Length - testString.Reverse().TakeWhile(c => !char.IsNumber(c)).Count());
```

**Edit:**

A shorter(and faster) way:

```
string result = testString.Substring(0, testString.LastOrDefault(testString.Last(char.IsNumber))+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of methods that can be used to achieve this. Here is a simple code snippet:

```
string src = "ABCD1234A_BC";
string search = "0123456789";
int pos = src.LastIndexOfAny(search.ToCharArray());
string dst = src.Remove(pos+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
public string StripAfterLastNumber(string input)
{
    //+1 because index is zero based
    int charsToTake = input.LastIndexOf(input.Last(c => char.IsNumber(c))) + 1;

    return input.Take(charsToTake).ToArray;
}
```

It looks for the position of the last numeric character in the input, and returns the input up to that point.

Answer (score 0):

Create an extension method of string like this:

```
public static class StringExtensions
```

{

```
  public static string RemoveExcessTextAferLastDigit(this string str)
  {
     //find the last index in the str of any number
     int lastIndex = str.LastIndexOfAny("1234567890".ToCharArray());

     return lastIndex > -1 ? str.Substring(0, lastIndex + 1) : str;
  }
```

}

This will allow you to invoke your extension as if it were native to the string class like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.RemoveExcessTextAferLastDigit();
  }
```

This passes your test.

Cheers,

CEC

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression

```
public string strip(string s)
{
  return new Regex(@"^[\d\D].*\d").Match(s).ToString();
}
```