# How to extract a substring after last occurence of an integer in a string

Tags: regex, string, perl

How to can extract a substring from a string based on the last integer in the string. For example, if I have following string

```
$my string = "_ZN7romcode6B0_rom3addEjj";
```

and I would like to get the substring after the last integer i.e. 3 in this case. How can I easily accomplish it using perl regex.

Comment: Related post: [remove everything after the last occurrence of numerical value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487662/remove-everything-after-the-last-occurrence-of-numerical-value)

Comment: For fun: `my $tail = reverse(scalar(reverse($string) =~ /^(\D*)/r));`

Answer (score 4):

I'd do:

```
my $string = "_ZN7romcode6B0_rom3addEjj";
my ($end) = $string =~ /(\D+)$/;
```

Where `\D`stands for any character that is not a digit.